# CentOS Stream 9 sda, sdb keep swapping OpenShift 4

Tags: linux, centos, kubernetes, openshift

I have an issue with the disks detection order on my OpenShift nodes.

My hypervisor is configured to have the disk with a smaller capacity, containing the CentOS image, as the first bootable disk. However, sometimes this disk, instead of being labeled as sda by the system, receives the label sdb, even though it was the first disk to boot. This causes my ignition file to malfunction since it specifies that the second disk should have the label sdb. I cannot statically add the disk to be taken as the first one by ID because the ignition file needs to be the same for both worker nodes, and these disks will have different IDs.

What can I do in this situation? I'd like to note that on my other cluster based on Fedora CoreOS, disks are detected in the correct order.

I've heard once something about `/sys/module/scsi_mod/parameters/scan` edition but I could not find any further information with this topic.

Regards

Comment: As usual, if there's an option for it, you should rely on other properties exposed in various /dev/disk/* (eg: LV name or uuid, disk wwn serial etc).